# Titanium Twitter Access token error

Tags: twitter, titanium

I developing application in Titanium Appcelerator. I had share image to twitter using the **social.js** [link](https://gist.github.com/rampicos/4320296)..It was worked great till yesterday. and i dont know is there anything updated in api , my share is not working and my error states "Can't get Access token" .

**MyCode:**

```
var social = require('/ui/common/social_plus');
var twitter = social.create({
consumerSecret : '1bXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxT0raQbg2Bhx',
consumerKey : '3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxffFx'
});

twitter.authorize(function() {
        twitter.shareImage({
            message : 'Share Via ',
            image : pic_loc,
            success : function() {
                alert('tweeted Succesfully!');
            },
            error : function() {
                alert("ERROR Tweeted!");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have you given the api key and secret token?

Comment: @Wahhab_mirza:yeah..it was working till yesterday and it suddenly saying  "Can't get Access token" . i thought it may expired and created a new key and applied, but that also saying the same prob ,no use..